# kops create cluster inside existing AWS vpc and subnets

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I am having a trouble creating a kubernets using kops inside existing AWS vpc and subnets.
I have an existing vpc with the following CIDR blocks:

**IPv4 CIDR:** 10.10.16.0/20

And in that VPC I have my subnets with their assigned CIDR blocks:

**SubnetDatabaseA:** 10.10.23.0/24

**SubnetDatabaseB:** 10.10.24.0/24

**SubnetDatabaseC:** 10.10.20.0/24

And so on...

when trying to create the cluster using kops I get this error:

```
 error running task "Subnet/ap-southeast-2a.clusters.dev1.k8s.local" (9m58s remaining to succeed): error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '10.10.18.0/23' conflicts with another subnet
        status code: 400, request id: 252367d1-d693-47b9-a6c5-a44908a0f6f7
```

Which means that one of my subnets is already using that IP range.

How can I assign kops to use a specific CIDR of my choice?

Because I can see that every time I try to create the cluster it assigns a different CIDR (example- CIDR                    10.10.18.0/23)?

Comment: Could you post full kops command about how you trying to create K8s cluster?

Comment: kops create cluster --name=$CLUSTER_NAME --state=$KOPS_STATE_STORE --zones=ap-southeast-2a --vpc=$VpcId --kubernetes-version=$k8sVersion --node-count=1 --node-size=t2.small

Comment: I've never used custom subnets for creating cluster through kops, but I believe that     `--network-cidr` or `--subnets` arguments will help you. Check all possible arguments via `kops create cluster -h`. And maybe next link will be helpful  https://icicimov.github.io/blog/virtualization/Kubernetes-Cluster-in-AWS-with-Kops/

Comment: Maybe this link will be also useful for you https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/run_in_existing_vpc.md

Comment: I will try your suggestions and post my comment as soon as I will get my conclussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kops create cluster --help
--subnets stringSlice                  Set to use shared subnets
--vpc string                           Set to use a shared VPC
```

See following

```
 kops create cluster --name=${CLUSTER_NAME} --vpc=vpc-1010af11 --subnets=subnet- 000e123a,subnet-123b456,subnet-888c9991 --master-zones=${ZONES} --zones=${ZONES}  --networking=weave
```

So, if you pass subnet ids, kops doesn't create new CIDR, instead, it will use provided subnet ids and corresponding CIDRs. refer following.

```
  subnets:
- cidr: 92.145.123.0/26
  id: subnet- 000e123a
  name: us-east-1a
  type: Public
  zone: us-east-1a
- cidr: 92.145.123.64/26
  id: subnet-123b456
  name: us-east-1b
  type: Public
  zone: us-east-1b
- cidr: 92.145.123.128/26
  id: subnet-888c9991
  name: us-east-1c
  type: Public
  zone: us-east-1c
```

Or you can edit the cluster with `kops edit cluster $CLUSTER_NAME` after running `kops create cluster` without `--subnets` flag and update the subnets section as seen above.

Reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_create_cluster.md

Answer (score 0):

For me, the requirement was to create the K8s cluster in existing VPC and Subnet. I was getting this error even after passing the VPCID, SUBNETID.

It worked for me when I changed my Master and Nodes Zones **us-east-1a** Same as Subnet zone (**us-east-1a**) in which I want to create.